# Error in View: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r

When I try to run the function , it receive the error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 0.

What can I do?

```
    install.packages("combinat")
    require(combinat)        

    df2 <- c(1234,1333,1332,1333,15,1234,15, 162, 1234)
    num2<- c(1,2,3,1,4,2,2, 2,3)
    data.frame(df2,num2)

    result1 <-combn(4, 2, function(reqn, df){
    names(Filter(identity,
           apply(table(df2, factor(num2, levels=reqn))>0, 1, all)))
    }, df=df2, simplify=FALSE)
    View(result1)
```

Comment: R can't convert a list with elements of different lengths to a data frame.

Comment: Is there no possibility?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: i want to open or to find a way to make the result show in table version.so I can see it better because I have a large file

Comment: Yes, but how do you want to convert a list of elements of different lengths to a tabular format? The reason R can't do that is because there are different ways depending on how you want to display it. Have you tried `simplify = TRUE`?

Comment: Yes i did. but then it gives me not the right result...

Comment: Since you insist on not providing any information that would help in assisting you, I'm going to move on. Good luck.

Comment: "it gives me not the right result" means you must know what the "right" result is...so what is it?

Comment: For example: combn(3,2) ...simplify=FALSE:
str(result1)
List of 3
 $ : chr [1:2] "1234" "1333"
 $ : chr "1234"
 $ : chr "1234"
For example: combn(3,2) ...simplify=TRUE:
str(result1)
chr [1:2, 1:3] "1234" "1333" "1234" "1234" "1234" "1333"

Which is not the same. I need the first one. But also need to open it. to see the results in table form. But there is no way to do it, like i want.